# Write HeartRate on HealthKit

Tags: apple-watch, healthkit

I have a problem to send the heart rate data to healthkit.
I want to read (in apple watch display) and write the heart rate data for my apple watch app.
i don't have any problem to read, but i can't send data.

```
func updateHeartRate(samples: [HKSample]?) {
    guard let heartRateSamples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else {return}
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        guard let sample = heartRateSamples.first else{return}
        let value2 = sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(self.heartRateUnit)
        self.label.setText(String(UInt16(value2)))
        let now = NSDate()
        print(value2)
        print(now)
        self.animateHeart()
        let completion: ((Bool, NSError?) -> Void) = {
            (success, error) -> Void in
            if( error != nil ) {
                print("Error saving HR")
            } else {
                print("HR saved successfully!")
            }
        }
        self.healthStore.saveObject(sample, withCompletion: completion)
```

In display: print("HR saved successfully")

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: instead of the string "Error saving HR", print the value of `error` to get more details.

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong to write. the program print:" HR saved successfully " But when i go to health app, there are not heart rate data.

Comment: What are the contents of the error? Did request authorization to save heart rate samples?